# Doctrine2 Paginator

Tags: orm, symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm

Starting with version 2.2 Doctrine has [Paginator](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html). There is only one example in the documentation:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoin = true);

$c = count($paginator);
foreach ($paginator as $post) {
    echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
}
```

There is nothing new in this class since the whole process described in the documentation can be done with `$query->getResult()`.

I know there are some bundles about pagination but I don't want to install third party bundles for such trivial issues. On the other hand, I cannot find anything about pagination of doctrine2. There should be some useful methods of the class. Where can I find them? If there are not then what is the point of the whole class?

Comment: There seems to be a better tutorial here: https://anil.io/blog/symfony/doctrine/symfony-and-doctrine-pagination-with-twig/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine's paginator is not Symfony aware — it's low-level and Doctrine specific.

On the other hand, if you install [a 3rd party bundle](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=pager), you'll get pagination adapters for Doctrine ORM & ODM, Propel, plain arrays, etc. You'll also get Symfony integration and view helpers. At least [WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle) that I use does all these.

So, unless you're going with Doctrine only, I suggest you reconsider your position about a 3rd party bundle.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question bacause there is nothing Symfony-specific in the problem at hand. It would be better to have a doctrine-only solution instead. I'm having the exact same problem and am also wondering what is the point of the Paginator class.

Comment: AFAICT, the Paginator class exists solely to solve the problem which occurs when trying to use setMaxResults on a JOINed DQL query. Smacks of bad design to me, but apparently what do I know. >.<

Comment: To all those claiming and agreeing with the fact that this question is not Symfony specific, look closer at the "symfony" tag and the term "bundle(s)" used in the question. If you're interested in the `Paginator` class outside of the Symfony context, go ask a separate question instead of downvoting the answer that solved the OP's needs 6 damn years ago.