# Symfony Doctrine Pagination

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity users, example count 90355 and I need get by 100 users and do something logic with this user. then next 100 use, this is I have but when I findAll my server dropdown how to solved this problem ?

```
public function find()
{
    $developers = $this->em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'desc'));
    foreach ($developers as $developer) {
       $this->getApiFullContact($developer);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I think like this function but setFirstResult and setMaxResults dynamics variable ?

```
    public function getPaginationUser()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Users', 'd')
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults(100)
        ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

how do this iteration ?

Comment: Just do `($page-1) * 100;` where $page is the page number requested, and use that instead of 0 in setFirstResult. Also there's no reason to do getQuery / getResult twice. Just remove the first two calls you have there.

Comment: how I know how call function and maybe first result and max result dynamic variable ? I update my question

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: don't need render to template I run command with cron and do something logic with users, KnpPaginatorBundle help with this ?

Answer (score 17):

I threw this example together from a couple things I have found and it seems to work. This is pretty basic but it is a start.

SO answer: [Doctrine2 Paginator getting total results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906051/doctrine2-paginator-getting-total-results)

Symfony Docs: [Querying for Objects Using Doctrine's Query Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder)

```
/**
 * @Route("/users/{page}", name="user_list", requirements={"page"="\d+"})
 */
public function getUsersByPage($page = 1)
{
    // get entity manager
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    
    // get the user repository
    $developers = $em->getRepository(Users::class);
    
    // build the query for the doctrine paginator
    $query = $developers->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC')
                        ->getQuery();

    //set page size
    $pageSize = '100';
    
    // load doctrine Paginator
    $paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);

    // you can get total items
    $totalItems = count($paginator);

    // get total pages
    $pagesCount = ceil($totalItems / $pageSize);

    // now get one page's items:
    $paginator
        ->getQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($pageSize * ($page-1)) // set the offset
        ->setMaxResults($pageSize); // set the limit

    foreach ($paginator as $pageItem) {
        // do stuff with results...
        dump($pageItem);
    }

    // return stuff..
    return [$userList, $totalItems, $pageCount];
}
```

Comment: in the query, the orderBy key should be u.id  and NOT d.id
     $query = $developers->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC')
                        ->getQuery();

Answer (score 5):

Fully *working* example is here -> [Using limit and offset in doctrine query builder for manual pagination](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/0s5l/using-limit-and-offset-in-doctrine-query-builder-for-manual-pagination). I'm just giving you the codes you need to understand first.

This is how it works and to me it is the best practise! Maybe not for everybody else!

1. Request goes to Controller
2. Controller calls Service
3. Service normalised request parameters with Trait
4. Service pulls data from Repository
5. Repository returns result back to Service
6. Service passes result to Factory
7. Factory creates result Model
8. Factory returns result Model back to Service
9. Service returns result Model back to Controller

**REPO**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

class StudentRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param string|null $name
     * @param int         $limit
     * @param int         $offset
     *
     * @returns array
     */
    public function findPaginatedByName($name, $limit, $offset)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

        if ($name) {
            $qb->where('s.name = :name')->setParameter('name', $name);
        }

        $qb->setMaxResults($limit)->setFirstResult($offset);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT);
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function findPaginatedByNameCount($name)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')->select('COUNT(s)');

        if ($name) {
            $qb->where('s.name = :name')->setParameter('name', $name);
        }

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
    }
}
```

**PAGER TRAIT**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Util;

trait PagerTrait
{
    public function getPage($page = 1)
    {
        if ($page < 1) {
            $page = 1;
        }

        return floor($page);
    }

    public function getLimit($limit = 20)
    {
        if ($limit < 1 || $limit > 20) {
            $limit = 20;
        }

        return floor($limit);
    }

    public function getOffset($page, $limit)
    {
        $offset = 0;
        if ($page != 0 && $page != 1) {
            $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        }

        return $offset;
    }
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Service;

use Application\BackendBundle\Factory\StudentFactoryInterface;
use Application\BackendBundle\Model\Student\Result;
use Application\BackendBundle\Repository\StudentRepository;
use Application\BackendBundle\Util\PagerTrait;

class StudentService implements StudentServiceInterface
{
    use PagerTrait;

    private $studentRepository;
    private $studentFactory;

    public function __construct(
        StudentRepository $studentRepository,
        StudentFactoryInterface $studentFactory
    ) {
        $this->studentRepository = $studentRepository;
        $this->studentFactory = $studentFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param int    $page
     * @param int    $limit
     *
     * @return Result
     */
    public function get($name, $page, $limit)
    {
        $page = $this->getPage($page);
        $limit = $this->getLimit($limit);
        $offset = $this->getOffset($page, $limit);
        $total = 0;

        $result = $this->studentRepository->findPaginatedByName($name, $limit, $offset);
        if ($result) {
            $total = $this->studentRepository->findPaginatedByNameCount($name);
        }

        return $this->studentFactory->createStudentResult($result, $name, $page, $limit, $total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

How I do pagination on symfony

```
/**
 * @Route("", name="admin_number_pool", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(NumberPoolRepository $repo, NumberPoolCategoryRepository $categories, Request $request): Response
{
    $page = $request->query->get('page', 1);
    $limit = 10;
    $pagesCount = ceil(count($repo->findAll()) / $limit);
    $pages = range(1, $pagesCount);
    $pools = $repo->findBy([], [], $limit, ($limit * ($page - 1)));


    return $this->render('admin/number-pool/index.html.twig', [
        'numberPools' => $pools,
        'categories' => $categories->findAll(),
        'pages' => $pages,
        'page' => $page,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. Reading **all** entities through `$repo->findAll()` looks like overkill, as this loads ALL entities just to count them

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, you're right. I was a little hasty here. Indeed, if there is a lot of data in the database, it will be impractical. Thank you for your comment.