# Symfony number of items (news)

Tags: php, symfony

How to change the number of displayed news. I know that the default value is 10.

[news/index.html.twig](http://pastebin.com/wEqhzD8b)

One more question. Here is the code for a single news

[news/view.php.twig](http://pastebin.com/6U0iFkef)

I would like to show up next to him, the previous two items (news). How to do that?

Comment: It is not in the template, in any case. Have a look at the controller code and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Doctrine? If you do take a look at this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#limiting-the-result

If you can access only to twigs file, you can use a conditional and check for the index of the collection using twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Example:

`{% for item in news %}
    {% if loop.index < 10 %}
{% endfor %}`

You can read more about pagination here: [Symfony Doctrine Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463859/symfony-doctrine-pagination)