# Pagination with Search Result - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, pagination

I am using ORM paginator for pagination

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
```

How can I paginate search results? Is  there any way to pass parameters with page number or I will have to use Session to pass parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 Paginator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106695/doctrine2-paginator)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Symfony2 bundle? 2 of the most used are:

- [WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle)
- [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle)

Comment: I am also using something like "ankii" , how can I paginate my search results by not using any 3rd party?